# why calling split and splice gives empty array?

Tags: javascript

In this JavaScript, why don't i get `azbc`?

```
var x = "a-b-c".split('-').splice(1, 0, 'z');
alert(x.join(''));
```

`split` returns an array containing `a`, `b` and `c`.

Shouldn't `splice` insert `z` after `a` and gives me `azbc`?

Why do i get an empty array?

note:
i know that what i want can be accomplished by:

```
var x = "a-b-c".split('-')
x.splice(1, 0, 'z');
alert(x.join(''));
```

since `splice` "modifies" the original array itself. shouldn't it modify `{a,b,c}` to `{a,z,b,c}` and then be assigned to `x`?

got it... the code below helped me to understand.

```
var x = "a-b-c".split('-')
x = x.splice(1, 0, 'z');
alert(x.join(''));
```

Comment: *it returns the removed elements*, so no, it wouldn't be assigned to x. The only thing assigned to x is going to be whatever elements are removed, in this case none. The bottom line is if you want to splice an array you have to store it in a variable first otherwise you will lose the result in a chain-type expression like the one you have.

Comment: JavaScript does not distinguish itself here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns the removed items from the array, not the new array:

```
> x = 'a-b-c'.split('-');
["a", "b", "c"]
> x.splice(1,0,'z');
[]
> x
["a", "z", "b", "c"]
> x.splice(1,1,'x');
["z"]
> x
["a", "x", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Paolo said, splice modifies the array in place http://jsfiddle.net/k9tMW/

```
var array = "a-b-c".split('-');
array.splice(1, 0, 'z');
alert(array.join(''));
```

Answer (score 1):

[Mozilla Developer Network-Array splice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) - Changes the content of an array, adding new elements while removing old elements.

***Returns***-
An array containing the removed elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned.

```
var x = "a-b-c".split('-');
x.splice(1, 0, 'z');
document.write(x + "<br />");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do like this,

```
var x = "a-b-c".split('-');
x.splice(1, 0, 'z');
alert(x.join(''));​
```